# If $f:[0,1]\to\mathbf{R}$ is continuous, and that $\int_0^1 f(x)x^k \, dx = 0$ for all integers $k>2004$, show that $f = 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

> If $f:[0,1]\to\mathbf{R}$ is continuous, and that $\int_0^1 f(x)x^k \, dx = 0$ for all integers $k>2004$, show that $f = 0$.

My intuition is using the Weierstrass Approximation Theorem or the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem. Consider the algebra $$A = \{\sum_{k=2005}^N c_k x^k + c_0 : c_i \in \mathbf{R}, N\in \mathbf{N}, N>2004\}$$ which vanishes nowhere ($1\equiv g(x) \in A$) and separates points (for every $x\not=y$, there is a $h\in A$ such that $h(x)=1, h(y)=0$). I'm now able to show that $$\displaystyle\left|\int_0^1 f^2 \, dx - \int_0^1 cf(x) \, dx\right|<\epsilon$$ for some constant $c$.

I'm wondering if I'm on the right track and, if so, where to go after this.

Comment: How about showing that $\tilde{f}(x) = x^{2005}f(x)$ is zero?

Comment: @sos440 Why not turn that into an answer (read: hint)? It's a great hint.

Comment: @sos440 how exactly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Hint.** If we let $\tilde{f}(x) = x^{2005}f(x)$, then

$$ \int_{0}^{1} x^k \tilde{f} (x) \, dx =0 \quad \text{for} \quad k=0,1,2,\cdots .$$

What can you say about $\tilde{f}$ and $f$?

Comment: Gotcha. Now we can use Weierstrass. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve the problem is to consider taylor representation of $f(x)$:

\begin{eqnarray}
    f(x) = \sum_{n=o}^{\infty} c_n x^n
    \nonumber\\
    &{}&
    \nonumber\\
    \int_0^1 f(x) x^k dx &=&0
    \nonumber\\
    &{}&
    \nonumber\\
    &=& \sum_{n=o}^{\infty} c_n\int_0^1 x^{k+n} dx =0
    \nonumber\\
    &{}&
    \nonumber\\
    &=& \sum_{n=o}^{\infty}\frac{c_n}{n+k+1} =0
    \nonumber\\
    &{}&
    \nonumber\\
    &\to& \frac{c_n}{n+k+1} =0
    \nonumber\\
    &{}&
    \nonumber\\
    &\to& c_n =0, \hspace{5mm} then \hspace{3mm}f(x)=0                           \hspace{3mm}_{\square}
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: This won't work. The function $f$ my not be representable as a Taylor series.